# Disable Outlook's inbuilt location textbox from an addi-in

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

How can I disable (make it read-only) the location textbox in the meeting dialog via Outlook add-in using C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to find the child window handle of that controls (FindWindow etc.) and disable it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you provide the code to accomplish this. I am using below code to open new meeting dailog:-

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Outlook.AppointmentItem agendaMeeting = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)this.Application.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
            agendaMeeting.MeetingStatus = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting;
            agendaMeeting.Location = "My meeting place";
            agendaMeeting.Display();
        }

Comment: I do not have any code to do that since I never did what you want to do. Generally, you'd need to call AppointmentItem.GetInspector, cast the returned Inspector object as IOleWindow, call IOleWindow.GetWindow to retrieve the HWND of the inspector. Once you have the window handle, use EnumChildWindows to enumerate the child controls. Once you find the control that you are after, call EnableWindow to disable it.

Comment: To figure out which control is the Location edit box, take a look at an appointment inspector with Spy++ (comes with VS) - click Search | Find Window, then drag the Finder tool on top of the Location edit box.| It looks like the class of that control is REComboBox20W. Don't know if that will be unique enough for your callback in EnumChildWindows to uniquely identity the Location edit box.